# Replace slash in to empty in bash

Tags: bash, macos, resx, slash

Let's suppose I have this results:

```
CMD_VAL = 'test/'
echo $CMD_VAL
=> test/

echo "$CMD_VAL"|sed 's#/##g'
=>test
```

but,

```
PRO_VAL = "$CMD_VAL"|sed 's#/##g'
echo $PRO_VAL
```

this returns

```
=> "test/ is a directory"
```

How should it need to change in order to get the "test" into a variable as a string?

Comment: Your Bash syntax is all wrong. Please post the actual commands you're running.

Comment: You are getting what appears to be an error message in trying to run `test/` as a command, not the contents of `PRO_VAL` (which remains empty, so the  "output" of `echo $PRO_VAL` appears after the error message. `sed` never actually produces any output, as it had no input.)

Comment: if [ "$IS_BUILD_COMMAND" = true ] && [ "$CMD_PRO_NAME_VAL" != "" ] && [ "$MICRO_GW_PROJECT_DIR" != "" ]; then
    echo $CMD_PRO_NAME_VAL
    echo "$CMD_PRO_NAME_VAL"|sed 's#/##g'

Comment: here $CMD_PRO_NAME_VAL = test/ and                                                     
echo "$CMD_PRO_NAME_VAL"|sed 's#/##g' I got  it as "test". I want to take it to variable and print

Comment: @chepner yes.how should I fix it?

Comment: Add your real code to the question; code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PRO_VAL=$(echo $CMD_VAL|sed 's#/##g')
```

you need to echo first, "$CMD_VAL"|sed 's#/##g" will be run $CMD_VAL and pipe to sed,it's not correct.

Comment: Please always double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$CMD_VAL"`), to prevent weird parsing under some circumstances.

Comment: This doesn't work if my input has spaces. val1/ val2/ val3/ Looking to remove all slashes.

Answer (score 4):

No need to spawn an external process. c.f. [this cheat-sheet](https://devhints.io/bash) for a guide on things like using the interpreter's built-in string processing tools.

```
$: CMD_VAL='test/'       # no spaces...
$: CMD_VAL=${CMD_VAL%/}  # strip the training slash
$: echo "$CMD_VAL"
test
```

Comment: Removing *all* slashes is more complicated, but can be done: `"${CMD_VAL//\//}"`. To explain it: the first `//` means "replace all occurrences of", then `\/` is an escaped forward slash (escaped since `/` would otherwise be a delimiter), then `/` is the delimiter between the pattern and its replacement, and then there's a blank replacement string. Whee!